# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after build Success in maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, maven-plugin

Application Build got successful but getting the following error :

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownHooksInOrder(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:52)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 2 more
```

I added this hadoop-common jar which has this class in pom file, classpath or any possible way i knew and could google but nothing worked.

Comment: I dont think this has to do with the maven built of *your own* stuff? This is more some kind of class path setup issue on the system running things.

Comment: @GhostCat I included the jar in the classpath but was of no help. Can you suggest something or any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a runtime problem. What I understand is that ClassRealm is trying to load a class at runtime and that class is not present in the jar. Just give it a look to the SelfFirstStrategy.java:50 and check if the class that is trying to be loaded actually exists.

Comment: i checked and the class is there in the jar.